# Cluster index on varchar on small table

Tags: sql-server

Hy guys,

I inherited a database with the following table with only 200 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Value] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [EffectiveStartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EffectiveEndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](2000) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see there is a Clustered PK on a UniqueIdentifier column. I was doing some performance checks and the most expensive query so far (CPU and IO) is the following:

```
SELECT @Result = Value
FROM MyTable
WHERE @EffectiveDate BETWEEN EffectiveStartDate AND EffectiveEndDate
AND Name=@VariableName
```

The query above is encapsulated in a UDF and usually the udf is not called in a select list or where clause, instead it's return is usually assigned to a variable.

The execution plan shows a Clustered Index Scan

Our system is based in a large number of aggregations and math processing in real time. Every time our Web Application refreshes the main page, it calls a bunch of Stored Procedures and UDFs and the query above is run around 500 times per refresh per user.

My question is: Should I change the PK to nonclustered and create a clustered index on the Name, EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate in a such small table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you should not. You can just add another index which will be covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX [IDX_Covering] ON dbo.MyTable(Name, EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate) 
INCLUDE(Value)
```

If `@VariableName` and `@EffectiveDate` are variables with correct types you should now see index seek.

I am not sure this will help, but you need to try, because index scan of 200 rows is just nothing, but calling it 500 times may be a problem. By the way if those 200 rows are in one page I suspect this will not help. The problem may be somewhere else, like opening a connection 500 times or something like that...

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed what I was imagine. I have no connections issue as all is done inside the database.